# My computers is running slowly, any tips?

Tags: firefox

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS and my entire system is really slowly.  For example when I open Firefox it takes maybe 45 seconds sometimes for the homepage to load.  My DAW Ardour crashes much more often than usual and I'm wondering is there a simple command I might try typing into the terminal that could maybe simply fix or at least diagnose my problem?

Comment: Please edit your question adding some hardware information. Make and model of processor, how much memory, ...

Comment: Getting an SSD to replace your hard disk would give you up to 10 times more speed.

Comment: Can use system monitor or type ' top ' in terminal to see if anything is using up system resources.

Comment: Thanks crip659!!